# SQL enter different in SELECT table than actual table data, based off if statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm new to SQL but haven't been able to find a good way to do what I'm trying to do here.

Goal: Enter different data in a column than what would normally be retrieved by the SELECT, based off of criteria

In the example below I want all data in column A of Table 1, but I want to replace all instances of 'C' with 'X'.

```
IE:
Table 1            Table 2
----------------------------
| A  |  B |       | A  | C |
-------------------------------
| y  | 5  |       | y  | 17 |
-------------------------------
| z  | 2  |       | z  | 8 |
```

Selected data:

```
--------------
| C  |  
------------
| X  | 
------------
| 8  | 



SELECT
t.C

FROM Table1 t with(nolock)
INNER JOIN Table2 tp with (nolock)
ON tp.A = t.A

WHERE t.a in ('y', 'z')
```

(The WHERE statement may be a bit off for this example, trying to translate my code at work into non-propitiatory language, and I only 70% understand what I'm doing with this)

The main idea is that I selected the data in the 'C' column but replace the instance of data '17' with value 'X'. The code written would not do this replacement, just wanted the structure that I have right now. Note that this just changes the data in the select table, but does NOT update the Table 2 data on the server.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

=================================

**Solution used thanks to Barmar**

```
SELECT
t.A,
CASE WHEN (t.C = 17), THEN 'X' else t.C END [Title of Column]
```

And the rest of the statement was the same. Note that this DOESN'T work with the above example though because the C column data is numbers, and I want to replace it with an 'X' char. You can either replace it with the same data type, or in the ELSE statement default replace that column with 'some other string value' and it'd work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IF` or `CASE`

```
SELECT IF(t2.C = 17, 'X', t2.c) AS C
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.A = t2.A
WHERE t1.A IN ('y', 'z')

SELECT CASE t2.C
        WHEN 17 THEN 'X'
        ELSE t2.C
       END AS C
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.A = t2.A
WHERE t1.A IN ('y', 'z')
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get your first case to work for me, but the WHEN statement did work well (though I didn't use the 'AS' statement. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

There a number of ways of doing this, deciding which is best would be dependent on the wider requirements.  @barmar has given a couple of ways my preferred way would be to use a decode as per the below.

```
with T1 as (select 'y' as A, '5' as B from dual
               union select 'z', '2' from dual),
T2 as (select 'y' as A, '17' as C from dual
            union select 'z', '8' from dual)
select decode(T2.C, 17, 'X', T2.C) from T1
inner join T2 on T1.A = T2.A
where T1.A in ('y', 'z');
```